# Charge Density Triple Integral to infinity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

OK, I'm given a charge density function $\displaystyle \frac{2\cdot10^{-4}}{1 + \rho^3}$, and the spherical coordinate of $0 \le \rho < \infty$.  Task: find total charge of cloud.

Is the answer the following?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2\cdot10^{-4}}{1+\rho^3} \rho^2 \sin \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

If I set the problem up this way, the triple integral appears to diverge, which doesn't make sense because the charge density function definitely converges.

This is for Calc III

Thank you

Comment: It does diverge because you should end up with $\ln(1 + \rho^3)$ which does diverge.

Comment: So the issue is "How do I find the charge of the cloud if the integral diverges?"

Comment: Wait.  I don't need p^2 and sin(phi) unless I'm converting from rectangular, do I?  Is that where I screwed up?

Comment: You didn't screw up.  The integral diverges, and hence the total charge is infinity.

Comment: Well, then, THANKS!!  I didn't know that was a possible answer.  Wish I could have the last two hours of my life back!